# BooleanField checkbox not render correctly with crispy_forms using bootstrap

Tags: django, forms, checkbox, twitter-bootstrap-3, django-crispy-forms

I am using crispy_forms and FormHelper. I have a model field declared as:

```
active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

And in my ModelForm, I have tried both the following in my Layout:

```
    self.helper.layout = Layout(
                    ...
        InlineCheckboxes('active'),
        Field('active'),
                    ...
```

which both not providing the desired result:

Please see [image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cf2Lt.jpg)

While using InlineCheckboxes, I do not see the checkbox and using only Field, it's not formatted correctly.

Please help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the [link](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/layouts.html#bootstrap-layout-objects) to the "Bootstrap Layout objects" section of Crispy Forms docs.

> **InlineCheckboxes**: It renders a Django forms.MultipleChoiceField field using inline checkboxes

InlineCheckboxes isn't appropriate for your model's field-type.

---

A hacky way to achieve what you're looking for is to use `PrependedText` with an empty string for the `text` argument.

```
...
PrependedText('active', ''),
...
```

---

Examining the source it appears that a boolean field by default renders the `<input>` tag inside the `<label>` tag. Using the hack above, 'Active' stays in the `<label>` and the `<input>` is put where you'd expect: in a `<div>` with "control" css class. Compare the following:

`PrependedText('active', '')`:

```
  <div id="div_id_active" class="form-group">
    <label for="id_active" class="control-label">Active</label>

    <div class="controls">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="active" class="checkboxinput" id="id_active" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

`Field('active')`:

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <div id="div_id_active" class="checkbox">
      <div class="controls">
        <label for="id_active" class=""><input type="checkbox" name="active" class=
        "checkboxinput checkbox" id="id_active" /> Active</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

### Update

I've confirmed that this is fixed in the dev branch of django-crispy-forms.

Reference this commit: [5c3a268](https://github.com/maraujop/django-crispy-forms/commit/5c3a2680e2a0a607208e897dc5c278436b69f681)

And this github issue: [#267](https://github.com/maraujop/django-crispy-forms/issues/267)