# Add CSS class to django-crispy form using hacked inline checkbox for Boolean

Tags: css, django, django-crispy-forms

I'm using crispy-forms to generate an inline-checkbox for a Boolean field using this workaround [BooleanField checkbox not render correctly with crispy_forms using bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22002861/booleanfield-checkbox-not-render-correctly-with-crispy-forms-using-bootstrap/22233485#22233485), which works great except I can't seem to get my css_class to pick up.  I've tried every configuration I could think of.

```
    Div(
        Row(
            Field('role',
                  wrapper_class='col-md-6'),
            Field('status',
                  wrapper_class='col-md-6'),
        ),
        Row(
            Field('sub_status',
                  wrapper_class='col-md-6'),
            PrependedText('smarts_monitoring', '',
                          wrapper_class='col-md-6'), #this one doesn't show up 
        ), css_class='attribute_group')
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

`PrependedText` doesn't work that way.

Try `PrependedText(Field('smarts_monitoring', wrapper_class='col-md-6'), '',)`